# Can the Wii U Remote Plus be used to play Wii games?

Tags: nintendo-wii, zelda-skyward-sword, wii-u

I have a Wii U console. I ordered *The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword* and *The Legend of Zelda: Twilight Princess* from Amazon to be able to play them on my Wii U, since I never owned the Wii previously, and therefore couldn't play them.

Can the regular Wii Remote Plus be used to play the wii Games I just mentioned above? Such as this one here: [http://www.amazon.com/Nintendo-Wii-Remote-Plus-Black/dp/B0094X28J0/ref=sr_1_1?s=videogames&ie=UTF8&qid=1405732521&sr=1-1&keywords=wii+remote+plus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0094X28J0)

Comment: You can get a refurb Remote Plus + Nunchuck through the Nintendo Store for $25 right now. Works great for me! https://store.nintendo.com/ng3/us/po/browse/productDetailColorSizePicker.jsp?productId=prod150198

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, but note that both games require the Nunchuck attachment as well.

#### Requirements

- *[Twilight Princess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Twilight_Princess#Gameplay)* requires any kind of Remote, and a Nunchuck attachment.
- *[Skyward Sword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Skyward_Sword#Gameplay)* requires a Remote, MotionPlus, and a Nunchuck attachment.

#### Controllers

- There are two versions of the original **Remote** (or "Wiimote"):

  - The [original Remote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Remote) has more limited motion capability, but is sufficient for most games on the Wii.
  - Later versions, called **["Wii Remote Plus"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Remote#Wii_Remote_Plus)**, have the MotionPlus attachment (below) built-in.
  - Though some versions of the Remote might be branded "Wii U", [all Remotes work with both the original Wii and Wii U](http://www.nintendo.com/wiiu/accessories/), including when playing Wii games on the Wii U. There is no Remote that only works with the Wii U (though the Wii U does have its other stand-alone controllers exclusive to it).
- The **[Nunchuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Remote#Nunchuk)** is an attachment for the second hand, and is necessary for many "traditional" video games on the Wii.
- The **[MotionPlus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Remote#Wii_MotionPlus)** adds additional sensing capability to the original Remote, and also has a pass-through for additional accessories (such as the Nunchuck).

  - Any game requiring a Wii Remote with the MotionPlus attachment can instead use a Wii Remote Plus.

As the controller you've linked is a Wii Remote Plus, that means it can satisfy both the Remote and MotionPlus requirements of *Skyward Sword* (and will function like a regular Remote for *Twilight Princess*). However, if you don't have a Nunchuck, you'll need to get one in order to play either game.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will order them immediately, hopefully they will make it with the rest of the package!